# How to communicate ReactJs with jQuery Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, iframe

I know it's a BAD idea to integrate jQuery in ReactJs but in my use case i have to rewrite all the jQuery based code to reactJs.

## My Use Case

I have a react app that allows people to customize jQuery script (**script written in jQuery**, For Eg. a countdown timer script written in jQuery) and also people can see ***live preview*** of customization in react app and people can **export (download)** the customized jQuery script.

React app allows people to customize the countdown timer (like changing color, size, font) also these changes needs to reflect in a live preview section (so people can see the changes instantly) in same react app page (Just like w3schools code and preview).

### What I did

In my initial implementation

1. I had written the jQuery script for countdown timer.
2. In the react app the **live changes** in preview based on customizing is implemented with state and rewrite jQuery script in vanilla Js inside react.

This works, but I have **rewrite script** from jQuery to vanilla js to make it work.

### Ideas

1. Is it a good idea to show the countdown script inside an iframe in react app and when user customize let's say color and font, state updates and pass this to iframe to update the script accordingly to show the live preview?

Is there any other suggestions to solve this particular situation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't really get what your question is. So is it a react app which shows jquery code along side a preview of the result something like w3schools?

Comment: Yes, similar to that.

Comment: It seems like your approach makes sense. Any problems with it?